# How to populate a column by inserting certain number of words from another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table of imported text data where 'body' column contain news articles of different length and 'description' column is empty.

I am wondering how to populate all the description rows by 200 words from their corresponding 'body' rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

This query will select everything up until the 200th space:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(YourTextField, ' ', 200);
```

So to update all the rows use:

```
UPDATE tableX set description=SUBSTRING_INDEX(body, ' ', 200);
```

where `body` and `description` are your columns

Comment: I may have been ambiguous in the question. I need a query to capture any string in 'body' column and truncate it to 200 words and insert that in 'description' column. If I understand correctly 'YourTextField' in your answer gets a string as input. I rephrased my question in terms of rows and columns.

Comment: It's the same... Just use and UPDATE. `UPDATE tableX set description=SUBSTRING_INDEX(body, ' ', 200)`; body can be your column. If the answer solves your question plz mark as solution!

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I wnated. Please update your answer with more complete one and I'll select it. Thanks.